# How to disable tooltips with shortcuts in PhpStorm 2016.3?

Tags: phpstorm

When I am trying to close some of the tools - can't do it immediately. Seems like it happens because of tooltips with shortcuts. They are "overriding" layer of the close button and I can't click this button. I need to wait till toltip will disappear.

I found only one setting about this tooltips - "tooltip initial delay". But changing this settings do not help.

How can I disable this tooltips at all if possible?

Here is tooltip which I am talking about:

[image: Here is tooltip]

Comment: 1) These tooltips do not appear immediately but after 1 or 2 seconds delay only. So it's a bit hard for me to understand how you "cannot click on the button immediately" 2) You can use keyboard shortcut to perform  that action (that has shortcut listen in tooltip) -- much faster than moving mouse anyway. 3) AFAIK delay for such tooltips should usually be controlled from OS settings side (no guarantee though)

Comment: 1) I just clicking close button and can't close tool window. I don't really know what is the real reason.

Comment: Now i am opened PhpStorm and all is fine. But this behavior annoys me from time to time.
2) It is possible, but i don't want to learn all shortcuts just because of this behavior.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130207 perhaps? (or one of the related tickets) Watch (star/vote/comment) it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I suggest you to map key (F12 in my case) to "Hide All Tool Windows"